# Sort DataFrame by multiple columns in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dataframe

new to csharp here. I'm struggling with sorting dataframe (Microsoft.data.analysis) by multiple columns in customer order?

I see there is orderby for single column sorting. But not able to figure out for multiple columns.

`public Microsoft.Data.Analysis.DataFrame OrderBy (string columnName); public Microsoft.Data.Analysis.DataFrame OrderByDescending (string columnName);`

`Orderby` `.Thenby()` do not seem to work

In python it would be
`df.sort_values(by = ['Column1', 'Column2'], ascending = [True, False])`. What would be Csharp equivalent for this? Or is there any other method I could try?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sort` given by Microsoft.
Here is the syntax of using it. Also, attaching [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.spark.sql.dataframe.sort?view=spark-dotnet) for further reading.

```
public Microsoft.Spark.Sql.DataFrame Sort (params Microsoft.Spark.Sql.Column[] columns);
```

Comment: This seems to be a solution from a different library Microsoft.Spark.Sql. But I'm using Microsoft.Data.Analysis.DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not implemented yet. There is an open issue for this on Github.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5758

Also, method chaining does not work `df.OrderBy("category").OrderBy("unit_price")`, because the sorting is not stable.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/6443